# Why is the dot/period character used as file extension separator?

Tags: filesystems, file-extension

Why dot and not any other character? What's the historical reason behind it?

Comment: Who says it's a file extension separator? It's just a character in the name. The filesystem doesn't care about it at all.

Comment: Probably along the lines of "someone wanted to separate their files by type and used the `.` character, and people followed suit." When people started using it enough, it just became the convention and software developers people started treading it as the standard.

Comment: @Zuck Not really, OS doesn't care. Extension is only a concept. It mattered on old versions of FAT filesystems, but since LFN was introduced it's just a part of filename. File managers on Windows care. Linux programs mostly don't use extensions at all. It's just a convention.

Comment: If I open a .JPG file on Windows it will know that it has to open that file with the associated program rather than any other program. So its being used by Windows. How did dot get there and not any other character that is what my question is.

Comment: @Zuck, that's not windows/OS, that's your user shell (Explorer). You can very easily replace that with a different shell that uses question marks to determine filetypes, or one that uses magic bytes to determine filetypes. There is no kernelland OS code that cares about `.`'s.

Answer (score 6):

Early computer keyboards were based off typewriters, and other than the QWERTY arrangement that came from them, there weren't any standards.  The only non-alphanumeric keys that were consistently available and didn't require <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> were <kbd>.</kbd>, <kbd>,</kbd>, and <kbd>/</kbd>.  Slash was used in math to divide, so it makes sense that this divides the file system.  That just leaves comma, which would of made listing files very awkward.

In short, it was the logical choice given the circumstances.

[image]